# Convert function into 1 liner

Tags: haskell, parsec

After doing

```
>import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
```

and

```
>data Tag = MkTag String deriving Show
```

I have this function

```
parseDiv = do 
  string "<div>" 
  return (MkTag "div")
```

and I want to convert it into a 1 liner for ghci. I could have used :{ ... :} but want to understand why it didn't work. This is the 1 line

```
>let parseDiv  = do { string "<div>";return $ MkTag "div" }


<interactive>:7:5: error:
* Non type-variable argument
    in the constraint: Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* When checking the inferred type
    parseDiv :: forall s (m :: * -> *) u.
                Text.Parsec.Prim.Stream s m Char =>
                Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Tag
```

It works if I define it across multiple lines.

Comment: As the error says, you need to enable the `FlexibleContexts` language pragma, to restrict it to `Stream s m Char`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I added {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-} into ghci and tried to do the 1 liner again but got the same result.

Comment: you can not write that in `ghci`, for ghci, you set this with `:set -XFlexibleContexts`. The pragma is for a Haskell *file*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define this with [**`(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36-). This thus performs a functor mapping with `x <$ u = fmap (const x) u`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

parseDiv :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Tag
parseDiv = MkTag "div" <$ string "<div>"
```